# Scrapy Fobidden with changed user agent

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape yelp and for some reason, I keep getting forbidden despite using a custom user agent.

2020-06-07 15:36:43 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'yelpscraper', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'yelpscraper.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['yelpscraper.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'}

As you can see, I've overridden the user agent. However, I get this error:

020-06-07 15:36:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.yelp.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-06-07 15:36:44 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: https://www.yelp.com/?find_desc=gyms&find_loc=new+york+city%2C+ny&ns=1>

I've changed the user agent in the settings.py and in def start_requests through a yield statement, but no luck. I'm confused because when I use my browser, it works perfectly.

Comment: This might violate Yelp's TOS, BTW.    A quick search turns up a Quora post that you might look into. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-scrape-Yelps-data-for-free?share=1  It mentions you might email Yelp for permission.

Comment: In the future, you'll want to use the code formatting just like you would if you cared whether your question is legible to others

Answer (score 0):

When going after any high value target, one of the first things to do is switch off [`ROBOTSTXT_OBEY`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.1/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey) since they almost certainly have `Disallow: /` for anything you'd care about